# Renaming file issue

Tags: git, filenames

I've gotten through step 8, but when I attempt step 9, I get the following message "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

- What I type in for step 8 has been "git mv sample.txt exampl.txt"

  1. Open the Terminal/Git Bash and (using only the command line) create the following:
  2. Navigate to your Desktop or Directory: cd Desktop
  3. Once there, create a new directory named test: mkdir test
  4. Navigate into the test directory: cd test
  5. Check to see what's inside (it should be empty): ls
  6. Navigate back to Desktop: cd ..
  7. Move the sample.txt file into the test directory: mv sample.txt test
  8. Make sure this was successful: cd test press enter and then ls
  9. Rename the sample.txt file to example.txt

All the solutions I've found on google or githelp all seem to give me the same result.

Comment: The above series of exercises appears to have nothing to do with Git. There's no step to create a Git repository, so it's not surprising that Git commands that depend on a repository's existence are not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Torek means you forgot to initialize the git repo (after step 2): `git init`.

Welcome to stackoverflow and have fun with Git.